# Ceph backfilling and available space decrease

Tags: recovery, ceph, object-storage

I've recently just added an osd to my cluster and it started backfilling. The new osd disk max space is added to the cluster max size as expected. But there is a strange behaviour i can't understand.
While backfilling is going on my max available space keeps decreasing. Is this expected behaviour? Will there be a available space increase after backfilling is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is expected. I don't know the exact mechanism requiring this but during recovery/backfill the PGs that have to be remapped take additional space. After the remapping is finished you should see the expected results.